# Keyboard shortcut for adding to Reading List in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Chrome added a Reading List feature in late 2020 as an alternative to bookmarking. If you click the star to bookmark, you'll see both "Add Bookmark" and "Add to Reading List". **Is there a keyboard shortcut for adding to the Reading List?**

I know Cmd-d (Mac) for bookmarking, but the [shortcuts page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) doesn't say anything about Reading List.

P.S. I can't remember whether this was a Chrome flag I enabled or it appeared by default.

Comment: I have seen a number of questions posted about this but still no answers unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) Chrome Support Forum, there is not a keyboard shortcut for adding a website to your reading list. It will update if Google adds one.